Updating ESBuild from 0.24.0 to 0.24.1 throws strange errors
I am using tsup, which uses ESbuild, to build my libraries. Example: https://github.com/react18-tools/turborepo-template/actions/runs/12427963648/job/34698706616
When I tried investigating, I found that only changes in pnpm-lock file reflected update of ESBuild from 0.24.0 to 0.24.1
Here's the error:
X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"

    (define name):1:0:
      1 │ import.meta.url

How to fix this issue?
I do understand that issue is caused by esbuild 0.24.1. How do I make sure that pnpm update --latest -r does not update esbuild?

...go back to the version that worked until it's fixed upstream?

This question is similar to: Errors while starting vite + react. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As suggested in this thread, I had to add the override statement to root package.json as I am using workspaces.
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "esbuild": "0.24.0"
    }
  }


This is work after try to push main on Cloudflare Pages.
